# What does 目立ち mean?

Tags: kanji, definitions

目 is eye, and 立 is something like stand? I was thinking it meant something out of the norm when you see it, but that's just a guess. The full thing was 目立ちたい, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inclination is right. 目立{めだ}つ means to stand out.

目立ちたい would mean having something want to stand out.